# How do I compile and run code on Linux from INTERACTIVE COMPUTER GRAPHICS A TOP-DOWN APPROACH WITH SHADER-BASED OPENGL® (6th edition)?

Tags: linux, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm trying to compile and run the book's online code from http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/, but they only seem to have Mac and Windows versions; how do I run this on Linux? I've spent hours trying to get the dependencies and things right just to build the simple examples in chapter 2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Tony from the future! If you continue on the path you're on, you'll end up spending several more hours before figuring this out - the good news is that I've already done it, and have compiled the following steps to help you out!

1. `sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev`
2. From http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/, download the following files:

   - CHAPTER02/WINDOWS_VERSIONS/ [I just put these files in CHAPTER02/]
   - Common/InitShader.cpp
   - Everything in include/ (although CheckError.h was unnecessary)
   - (So, your base directory should now have the following folders: CHAPTER02, Common, and include.)
3. `cd CHAPTER02`
4. `g++ ../Common/InitShader.cpp example1.cpp -I../include -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lc -lm -lGLEW -o example1.out`
5. Make some changes to resolve errors:

   - add `#include <stdio.h>` to include/mat.h
   - If you get "X Error of failed request: GLXBadFBConfig", comment out these two lines in example1.cpp:

   `//glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 );
   //glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );`

   - If you get "error: GLSL 1.50 is not supported." change the first lines of fshader21.glsl and vshader21.glsl to say `"#version 130"` instead of 150
6. ./example1.out
7. Rejoice at finally seeing the Sierpinski Gasket!